# Priority Queue of custom Class using Comparator with argument on constructor in C++

Tags: c++, priority-queue, comparator

I want to create a `priority_queue` of the class `Edge` in C++.

For that, I created the `edgeCompare` comparator class as follows:

```
class edgeCompare{
public:
    map<int, glm::mat4x4> * Qmap;

    edgeCompare(const map<int, glm::mat4x4> & Qm){
        * Qmap = Qm;
    }

    bool operator() (const Edge & e1, const Edge & e2) const{
        // code that compares and returns corresponding bool
        // OBS: in this function I use *Qmap
    }
}
```

The thing is, as you can see, that I need an external variable to do the comparison.

A `priority_queue` is usually declared as:

```
priority_queue<Edge, vector<Edge>, edgeCompare> pq;
```

But in my case, I need to construct the `edgeComparator` with my variable `Qmap`.

How should I proceed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you solve this? I would like to do something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template parameter is the *type* of the comparator. You still need to pass an *instance* of the comparator to the priority_queue constructor, and that is when you can construct the comparator instance with whatever parameters you like.

For instance:

```
map<int, glm::mat4x4> m;
edgeCompare comp(m);
priority_queue<Edge, vector<Edge>, edgeCompare> pq(comp);
```

You can also create the `edgeCompare` object inline but extra parentheses are needed for disambiguation:

```
priority_queue<Edge, vector<Edge>, edgeCompare> pq((edgeCompare(m)));
```

Comment: What does disambiguation mean here? Why we need extra parentheses?
I mean if we have two or more class properties then we declare it like this

priority_queue<Edge, vector<Edge>, edgeCompare> pq(edgeCompare(m, n));

In this case the compiler doesn't throw any ambiguation error. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Overload `operator==`, `operator!=`, `operator>` and `operator<` in the `Edge` class so that you can just compare them `e1 == e2` in your comparator.

Also don't derive from `std::map`.  It does not have a `virtual` destructor, which makes it a bad idea to derive from it.

Just have your map as a private member to your class.

Comment: Yes, I did overload those operators... I just didn't mention it because I thought it was not important. 
You mean to make `std::map` a private member of the `Edge` class? In my specific problem, it wouldn't make any sense to do that. I need to get it from "outside".

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/priority_queue.html), there is an overload that allows you to pass in your predicate in `priority_queue`'s constructor.

Comment: Also in [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue), which concerns the C++ standard library.